# Is drag and drop functionality completely bugged with Apache Flex SDK 4.11?

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I use for the first time Apache Flex SDK since Adobe gave it to Apache and I want to implement simple drag and drop functionality on a Spark Datagrid to modify order of its items.

My simple test code:

```
<s:DataGrid dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" dataProvider="{_ac}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="a" />
            <s:GridColumn dataField="b" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Each time I drag/drop item from my datagrid to the same datagrid, my item is stored on second index...Is there any reason or is this bugged what would explain why it wasn't implemented in the last releases...

Comment: I did warn you that this is probably an experimental feature of the Spark DataGrid. You'd probably be better of asking this question on the [Flex user list](http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/) so that the developer who implemented this might pick it up.

Comment: ok thank you. I will sort my ArrayCollection on a field and use an item editor to let user modify this ArrayCollection. That should do the work.

Comment: unbelievable...editorDataField doesn't exist anymore for a GridColumn so we can not use an itemEditor. SDK sooooo bugged...

Comment: @OlivierJ. The Spark components set is different from the API of the MX Component set. I'm not sure if that is the same as "Bugged". Pleased read this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-7ff3.html regarding using itemEditors.  Based on the docs it appears the datafield is the replacement you need for "EditorDataField"; so the same API is used for displaying and editing the column.

Comment: for now, I moved back to SDK 4.6 because Spark DataGird dosen't seem to be much faster than mx DataGrid. Thanks for this clarification anyway, +1

Comment: The mx data grids are significantly faster and have a lot of bug fixes in Apache Flex 4.11 compared to Adobe Flex 4.6, so you may want to consider using it even if you don't use the spark data grid.

Comment: I will make a deploy with sdk 4.6 due to time consideration but after I will move to SDK 4.11 and make some performance tests to see differences between them. Thanks.